# Move elements of a matrix down java

Tags: java, matrix

I am trying that given a matrix, with any digit, if it finds zeros in it, lower the elements of those that are not null.
For example for the matrix

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  0  0
0 12  0 14  0
0  0 18 19  0
0 22 23 24 25
```

The output would be

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  2  3  4  0
0  7  8 14  0
1 12 18 19  5
6 22 23 24 25
```

Remaining the zeros above, moving the elements down in order. I have this code:

```
public static void displace(int[][] matrix, int size) {
    int cont=1;
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        cont = 1;
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            if (matrix[row][col] == 0) {
                matrix[row-1][col]=matrix[row][col];
                cont++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that makes me is to replace the first number of the row with a zero, that is, it takes the zero and a position goes up.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: That the code that I have does not work, that I do not do it well and I do not know the error. If you read everything, you can see that I've put "The only thing that makes me is to replace the first number of the row with a zero, that is, it takes the zero and a position goes up."

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: First I would like to do it to me. If I have already tried everything I know and do not want, it is when I ask for help. I only have this method and a print matrix, so I think it's pretty much debugged.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include details of what you found while debugging?

Comment: It will be easier for you if you'll save the columns as lists ;)

Comment: I try to make it as simple as possible. I could pass everything to an array and treat it from there but I try to treat it from the matrix itself.

Comment: I do not get anything. Only by console. In the debug anything.

Comment: And what are the usages of `int[] color` and `int position` arguments in this method?

Answer (score 1):

For future question consider posting [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like Joe C commented.
Remove whatever is not relevant (like `int[] color` and `int position` like STaefi commented) and provide the test data in an easy to use form, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] matrix1 =   {{1,2,  3 ,4 ,5},
                         {6,7,  8, 0, 0},
                         {0,12, 0,14, 0},
                         {0,0, 18,19, 0},
                         {0,22,23,24, 25}
    } ;

    displace(matrix1);
    for( int[] row : matrix1) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

As for the solution : you need to repeat the process, until all swaps are done.

```
public static void displace(int[][] matrix) {

    int swapCount= 1;

    while (swapCount > 0) {

        swapCount = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
                if (matrix[row][col] == 0) {
                    if( ((row-1) >= 0) && (matrix[row-1][col] != 0)) {
                        //do swap
                        matrix[row][col] = matrix[row-1][col];
                        matrix[row-1][col]= 0;
                        swapCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```